# Is it possible to use an ifelse statement with strings?

Tags: r

I"m attempting to read through a column and if I find a matching string write a new value to a new column. The code I started playing with looks like this

```
crime_dd$Offense_Cond <- ifelse(crime_data$Offense = 'TMVP','TFMV','MVTHFT','AUTOTH', "AUTO THEFT", "OTHER")
```

This doesn't work. I've tried using %in% but I am probably using it wrong if it even works at all in ifelse statements. Anyone have a elegant solution other than maybe using astr_replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `%in%` on a vector of values i.e to create a vector from multiple strings, use `c()`

```
ifelse(crime_data$Offense %in% c('TMVP','TFMV','MVTHFT','AUTOTH'), 
        "AUTO THEFT", "OTHER")
```

NOTE: In the OP's post, there is a typo for `==`

Comment: Ah. So close. That was almost exactly like the ifelse I used with %in% except I missed putting the values in a list.

Comment: @MixedBeans  It is a `vector`.  There is also another structure with `list`